# Accessibility of confirm dialog in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, dialog, accessibility, onbeforeunload, jaws-screen-reader

The confirmation dialogues in chrome are not accessible to JAWS screenreader (Version 18.0.2945). I experienced that with a simple *onbeforeUnload* dialog as well as with a javascript confirm dialog. The text in the dialog will not be read. Did anyone experience similar problems or knows an answer?

Comment: It might be a JAWS issue, and it might be not. Could you please provide some code for us to investigate? Thanks!

Comment: Here is the code i use to set the _beforeUnload_ behaviour:

`$(function() {
    $('.erfassung :input').on('change', function() {
        setConfirmUnload(true);
    });

    // Turn off the unload message whenever a form get submitted properly.
    $('form.erfassung').on('submit', function() {
        setConfirmUnload(false);
    });
});

function setConfirmUnload(on) {
    var message = "You have unsaved data. Are you sure to leave the page?";
    window.onbeforeunload = (on) ? function() { return message; } : null;
}`

Comment: And second for a confirm box i set a simple onclick-event:
`<h:commandButton value="Löschen" styleClass="button small" style="float: right; width: auto;"
                             onclick="if (!confirm('Wollen Sie die Person(en) wirklich löschen?')) return false;"
                             accesskey="ö"
                             title="...`

Comment: Sorry for the horrible formatting.

Comment: entschuldigung, ich habe vom ersten Beispiel nicht verstanden, ob Sie immer ein gewöhnliches `confirm` benutzen? Jedenfalls, werde ich es jetzt im Chrome mit JAWS prüfen :)

Comment: Im ersten Beispiel ist es kein gewöhnliches confirm sondern die Aktivierung einer Bestätigung onbeforeunload. Aber das gewöhnliche confirm geht ebenfalls nicht... Danke schonmal fürs Prüfen!

Answer (score 0):

As of today, 18/09/2017, this is a jaws issue. The code works on all other major browsers.
There is no solution at present.

Just for your information, alert and prompt have the same problem. 
HTTP basic authentication dialogs aren't usable either. Everything works with NVDA.

Freedom scientific, please, fix this issue.